# Manifest Merger error when using Espresso to test a project with minSdkVersion="14"

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am unable to build with the new manifest merger. Gradle is complaining that my tests are using `minSdkVersion="14"`, while Espresso has `minSdkVersion="8"`. I don't actually have a manifest my tests folder (`androidTest`), but it looks like the manifest merger is creating one in a temp folder.

Temp manifest created by the merger:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

    <instrumentation android:name="com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="mypackage.android"
                     android:handleProfiling="false"
                     android:functionalTest="false"
                     android:label="Tests for mypackage.android"/>
</manifest>
```

The error and debug log:

```
Merging uses-sdk with lower test manifest:5:5   
Merging application with lower test manifest:7:5
Merging result:ERROR                            
{PATH_TO_PROJECT}\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.jakewharton.espresso\espresso\1.1-r2\AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library test manifest
:MyApp:processDebugTestManifest FAILED          
:MyApp:processDebugTestManifest (Thread[Daemon Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.107 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApp:processDebugTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library test manifest
```

Any idea what I can do to resolve this, or is it a bug with the manifest merger?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    useOldManifestMerger true
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use the old manifest merger, I need this one to work.

Answer (score -1):

This issue will be resolved when this ticket's CL is released:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71147